# An ant is sitting at edge of a rotating disc, if ant reaches the other end, after moving along diameter, then angular velocity will?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, angular-momentum

an ant is sitting at the edge of a rotating disc, if the ant reaches the other end, after moving along the diameter, then the angular velocity will increase, decrease, or remain constant? will it first increase then decrease or first decrease then increase?
i don't know whether angular momentum will be conserved in this case or not please help

Comment: I think that the idea is: the ant has mass. So you must verify what happens with the momentum of inertia of the system due its movement. And then use the conservation of the angular momentum.

Answer (score 1):

Angular velocity is constant for a rotating rigid body about it's axis.As Angular velocity $\omega$ =$\delta$ $\theta$/$\delta$t.
That means angular velocity is rate of change of angle. And on a rigid body every point rotate with same $\omega$ .